# Get a RadComboBoxItem from an onclick hander for a checkbox in a template on the client side

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a Telerik RadComboBox with an item template. In the item template I have an ASP checkbox. I have a client onclick handler for the checkbox and in that I want to get the telerik RadComboBoxItem object and from that get the RadComboBox object. I can get the DOM elements by of the item by from checkbox.parentNode.parentNode. Telerik has a method to get the DOM element from a RadComboBoxItem, but how do I get the item from the DOM element?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Even with templates, you can set the text and value fields to bind I believe.  With that said, if you store the text in the checkbox, you should be able to get the master RadComboBox and find it with findItemByText method...  (mentioned here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/combobox/comboclsideobject.html).

You could also look at the HTML to see if the DIV for the combo box item has a unique ID; if it does, you could get the ID and use `$find(id)` to return you the item too.  I don't remember this if it does or not.

Some ideas, HTH

Comment: One could also use the findItemByValue method (mentioned in the article Brian linked), allowing for the usage of the value property to identify items.

Comment: Since templates are being used, the value would also have to be rendered in the HTML markup, I wasn't sure if that was happening, but if it is, yes this is also another viable solution.